# TFS: List changesets that have not been merged

Tags: changeset

### Environment

TFS 2010.  Three branches:  **Main**, **Development** and **Release**.

### Question

I would like to easily retrieve a list of changesets that have not been fully merged into all three branches.

#### For Example

Lets says I have a changeset, 100, that was a bugfix and checked in directly into **Release**.  I can use the Tracking feature to visualize that it exists only in Release.

But that requires me to know to look at that changeset.  I'm looking for a generic list that would show me any changeset that exists in one branch, but not in all three.

### What I know

I know I can compare Release to Main to see the differences.  Is that my only option?

I try to associate changesets with work items, so I could query a list of non-closed work items and then as a 'rule', I could verify that a changeset has been fully merged before closing it.  And perform code compare to verify.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get a simple list of changesets through the IDE by choosing the "Selected Changes" option when merging things onto a build.

Another option is to use the API. [VersionControlServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) has a property named [GetMergeCandidates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138934%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which returns an array of [MergeCandidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.mergecandidate.aspx) which has the changeset and if it has been partially merged already as properties.

Comment: Awesome. Getting the quick list from the Merge process will work for now. And when I have time I'll investigate using the API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

From the Developer Command Prompt, you can also use the [tf.exe merge command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
tf merge /candidate /recursive Release Main
```

will show you all the changesets that were made to Release but haven't been merged into Main.