# List of unmerged changesets between TFS branches at the command line?

Tags: command-line, powershell, merge, changeset

This question was asked already, but answered in a way that doesn't suit my needs while not precluding the solution I'm looking for. I'm not sure what the correct course of action is, so I'm asking again while linking to the other thread: [TFS: List changesets that have not been merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995576/tfs-list-changesets-that-have-not-been-merged)

I would like to get a of changesets that have not been merged from my main branch into a development branch. Going through the UI is possible, but there are a truly suffocating amount of entries in that list, and taking screenshots is not only incredibly laborious, but also incomplete as the changeset information is truncated in the un-resizeable window.

The prior thread was answered with citing an available API method, but I'm wondering more about powershell since that's the environment in which I would like to work with this information. Is there a way using tf.exe that I've missed that would allow me to do this? I know the Power Tools Cmdlets fairly well, and I'm fairly sure they don't have anything for this, but I did consider looking in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

> tf merge /candidate SOURCE_BRANCH TARGET_BRANCH

Example:

> tf merge /candidate Main Dev

Comment: NgM, I like you. Thanks a bunch!