# Modify "tf history" command to yield only unmerged changesets

Tags: powershell, command-line, tfs

I have two branches, `Apple` and `Banana`. Out of all the **unmerged** changesets in `Apple`, I only want to merge those that contain the term `MergeToBanana` in their check-in comments.

So far this is what I have in my PowerShell script:

```
Param (       
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [String]$ChangesetComment
       )

$tf = get-item "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.EXE"

if ($ChangesetComment) {
    echo "*** Looking for all changesets containing '$ChangesetComment' in their check-in comments. This might take a while. ***"
    $changesetsToMerge = & $tf history $/TeamProject/Server/Apple /noprompt /recursive | findstr $ChangesetComment  
    $changesetNumbers = $changesetsToMerge | % $_.changesetnumber

    echo "*** Now merging filtered changesets. ***"
    Foreach ($c in $changesetNumbers) {
        & $tf merge /version $_.c $/IMSDev/Closed/$ScdVersion . /r /noprompt    
    }
}
```

Given my example, `ChangesetComment` will be set to `MergeToBanana` when I run the script.

I would like to modify my `tf history` command so that it only yields information about changesets in `Apple` that are not yet merged into `Banana`, so that I don't have to search through the entire history for changesets that contain `ChangesetComment` in their check-in comments. How can I do so?

Any other advice on how to improve my script is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the  tf history command, you could try to use  `/candidate` option in [TF merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command)

> tf merge /candidate SOURCE_BRANCH TARGET_BRANCH

Example:

> tf merge /candidate Apple Banana

More detai ways please refer the answers in this question: [TFS: List changesets that have not been merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995576/tfs-list-changesets-that-have-not-been-merged)